# PostgreSQL declarative partition - unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm trying to create a partitioned table which refers to itself, creating a doubly-linked list.

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    category integer NOT NULL,
    time timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
    prev_event integer,
    next_event integer

) PARTITION BY HASH (category);
```

Once I add primary key I get the following error.

```
alter table test2 add primary key (id);
ERROR:  unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "test2" lacks column "category" which is part of the partition key.
```

Why does the unique constrain require all partitioned columns to be included?
EDIT: Now I understand why this is needed: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-LIMITATIONS

Once I add PK with both columns it works.

```
alter table test2 add primary key (id, category);
```

But then adding the FK to itself doesn't work.

```
alter table test2 add foreign key (prev_event) references test2 (id) on update cascade on delete cascade;
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "test2"
```

Since PK is not just id but id-category I can't create FK pointing to id.

Is there any way to deal with this or am I missing something?

I would like to avoid using inheritance partitioning if possible.

EDIT2: It seems this is a known problem. https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/di5mbr/postgresql_12_foreign_keys_and_partitioned_tables/f3tsoop/

Comment: What do you expect to gain by partitioning here? How many `category`s do you have?

Comment: Does each linked list contains elements of the same category only?

Comment: @Bergi around 100 to 1000 categories. I need to do per category or per category set SELECTs, so partitioning based on category would increase SELECT performance by 99% or more.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there is no straightforward solution. PostgreSQL simply doesn't support this as of v14. One solution is to use triggers to enforce 'foreign key' behavior. Other is to use multi-column foreign keys. Both are far from optimal.

Comment: A trigger to verify a constraint like this is [always subject to race conditions](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/).